# How to use Windows.Media.Editing for Video Editing in Windows Phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, video-editing

In the latest release of Windows Phone microsoft comes with video editing feature, that provides the ability to edit the videos from the app.

I used the ***dll(Windows.Media.Editing)*** for editing videos in the app. I take help from the channel 9 video for creating basic video trimming effect. You can found channel 9 video on this link http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2014/2-555.

I searched on google but not found any code related to video editing feature like **overlay text on video**, **apply filters effect**, **slow motion video** and lots more as said by microsoft.

Can anyone please share code, links for editing video for Windows Phone 8.1?

Comment: I don't know about overlay text (and I think that there's no chance to do it because they said that they don't support time-based effects for now), but you can take a look at this link http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-extensions-sample-7b466096/

Comment: Thanks StepTNT for you reply and link but the effects applied in this sample is on **MediaElement** tag not on Video itself so the effects are not retained after saving, I posted on MSDN here is the link [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/871c419e-938e-4f3b-ab4c-e2f7d59d3a38/exploring-windowsmediaediting-api?forum=wpdevelop)

Comment: If I'm not wrong, you can apply the same effects to a `Clip` opbject, so they'll remain when you export a `Composition`. It should work like this: 
`var composition = new MediaComposition();
var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(file, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(new VideoEffectDefinition("GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect"));
composition.Clips.Add(clip);`

Comment: ok, I need to try this and thanks for the help. You can post this in answer i will mark it as answer if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Windows.Media.Effects`. I found this the other day, which documents adding slow motion effects to a MediaCapture object. It's on the Windows Store site but applies to Windows Phone 8.1. Sorry I have not tried this code out, but [there's some example code on the page and it might lead you to other resources, like stabilisation and rotation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/dn643521.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code

```
var composition = new MediaComposition(); 
var clip = await MediaClip.CreateFromImageFileAsync(file, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));      
clip.VideoEffectDefinitions.Add(new VideoEffectDefinition("GrayscaleTransform.GrayscaleEffect")); composition.Clips.Add(clip);
```

using the `GreyscaleTransform` from http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/media-extensions-sample-7b466096/

Please note that I was not able to make this work outside the sample project because of some dependecies stuff that I don't understand